# Use jQuery or JS to hide div on different dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle, hide

When I select an option from the dropdown, a set of buttons associated with that selection appears in a div (where it should). I then click one of those buttons which causes a second div to appear (#info, green background) and content associated with the button to appear inside of the div (as intended).

**My issue is this:**

Once the second div has appeared, if I go back to the initial dropdown and select a different option, I want the green #info div to disappear, where it currently stays visible and contains the content associated with the last button clicked despite having selected a different dropdown option.

I would SO appreciate any help anyone can provide! Thanks so much for taking a look. So grateful to have access to all of your smart brainz.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lcunning/xkz7rddm/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "red") {
        $(".box").not(".red").hide();
        $(".red").show();

      } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "green") {
        $(".box").not(".green").hide();
        $(".green").show();
      } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "blue") {
        $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
        $(".blue").show();
      } else {
        $(".box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();

  $('.buttons button').click(function() {
    $('#info').empty();
    $('#info').html($("#" + $(this).data('link')).html());
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
#button-column {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
button {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
}
#info {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#dropdown {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.info {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown">
  <h3>I am a...</h3>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="green">Dinosaur</option>
    <option value="red">Unicorn</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="green box">
  <h3>Today I am feeling...</h3>
  <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="buttons">
      <button data-link="content">Content</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <button data-link="mad">Mad</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <button data-link="hungry">Hungry</button>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>

<div class="red box">
  <h3>Today I am feeling...</h3>
  <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="buttons">
      <button data-link="shy">Shy</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <button data-link="curious">Curious</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <button data-link="sleepy">Sleepy</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="info">

</div>
<div id="hiddenDivs" style="display:none;">
  <!-- Dinosaur Select -->
  <div id="content">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Laying in the sun is nice.</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mad">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Go knock some trees over!</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hungry">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Go make a salad!</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Unicorn Select -->
  <div id="shy">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>I like to hide in the forest.</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="curious">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Wait until everyone is asleep.</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sleepy">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Napping under a shady tree is the best.</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkz7rddm/1/).

You just need to hide and show the `#info` div on change or load.

So anytime the dropdown changes, that `#info` div will `hide`. And then, if someone clicks a button, it will `show`. That `show()` function will always run, but will be ignored if you're clicking on the button multiple times.

```
    });
    $("#info").hide(); // Hide
}).change();

$('.buttons button').click(function (){
    $("#info").show(); // Show
    $('#info').empty();
    $('#info').html($("#" + $(this).data('link')).html());
});
```